# Spring Boot Export Excel XSSFSheet Add Header Not Working

Tags: spring-boot, apache-poi, export-to-excel

I'm doing an excel export in spring boot. I add a title to thr beginning of Excel, bt excel is not added. Can you help? top to add title  "sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(firstRow, lastRow, firstCol, lastCol));"

```
private XSSFSheet sheet;

private void writeHeaderLine() {

        sheet = workbook.createSheet("Aday Mülakat Listesi");
       
        
        int firstRow = 0;
        int lastRow = 6;
        int firstCol = 0;
        int lastCol = 29;
        sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(firstRow, lastRow, firstCol, lastCol));
        Header header = sheet.getHeader();
        header.setCenter((HSSFHeader.font("Calibri", "regular")
                + HSSFHeader.fontSize((short) 14) + "My " + HSSFHeader.startBold() + "Styled"
                + HSSFHeader.endBold() + " Text with page number " + HSSFHeader.page()));


        Row row = sheet.createRow(7);

        CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        XSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setBold(true);
        font.setFontHeight(11);
        font.setFamily(FontFamily.ROMAN);
        cellStyle.setFont(font);
        cellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

        createCell(row, 0, "Name", cellStyle);
        createCell(row, 1, "Surname", cellStyle);
        createCell(row, 2, "School Name", cellStyle);
        createCell(row, 3, "", cellStyle);
       ....

    }
```

[image]